# Why does my C program output the memory address instead of the value?

Tags: c

Why does my C program output the memory address instead of the value?

I'm basically just taking user inputs as an array of ints and then trying to loop through the array to print each element out, but as soon as the program runs, it outputs I guess the 'memory addresses' of the elements instead of its actual value.

Please have a look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  
  int array[5]; //the array with x items
  int target = array[1]; //target is any second value of the array

  for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){ //taking 5 user inputs
    if (y == 0){
      printf("Enter your %dst item: ", y+1);
      scanf("%d", &array[5]);
    } else if (y == 1){    
      printf("Enter your %dnd item: ", y+1);
      scanf("%d", &array[5]);
    } else if (y == 2){
      printf("Enter your %drd item: ", y+1);
      scanf("%d", &array[5]);
    } else{
      printf("Enter your %dth item: ", y+1);
      scanf("%d", &array[5]);
    }
  }
  
  for (int x=0 ; x < 5; x++){ //printing out array
    printf("Array[%d] = %d\n", x, array[x]);
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should add your input and output to the question. Just copy&paste as formatted text.

Comment: With `&array[5]` you get a pointer to the *sixth* element of your five-element array.

Comment: "Why does my C program..." It does not. Your compiler might tell you about using variables without assigning a value before. You print values from an unitialized variable. And you read into a memory location that is beyond the bounds of your array.

Comment: And what is the purpose of `int target = array[1];`? At that point, what is the value of `array[1]`?

Comment: What is the purpose of that lengthy `if`-cascade? You have a loop counter. Use it. `scanf("%d", &array[5]);` => `scanf("%d", &array[y]);` That will also solve the issue with writing to illegal address `&array[5]`

Comment: int target = array[1]; was just this other line of code which will be later used in the program. It has nothing to do with the problem as of right now.

Comment: @SohailaAli But it's invalid: you are not allowed to read uninitialised memory.

Comment: You should enable more warnings in your compiler. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. Many errors that make you waste loads of time can easily be detected by the compiler. Don't waste that opprotunity!

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign any value to the array.

- `int target = array[1];` doesn't make sense, since the array is not initialized. C programs are executed from top to bottom, assignment doesn't create some magic relation between variables: `target` will not get magically updated later if `array[1]` eventually gets initialized. If you want something like that, you could use pointers instead.
- `&array[5]` doesn't make sense, since arrays in C are 0-indexed and you access the array out of bounds by writing to the 6th item. This causes undefined behavior and one possible outcome of undefined behavior is memory corruption.
- `printf("Array[%d] = %d\n", x, array[x]);` doesn't make sense, since again, the array has not been initialized. The values printed will have indeterminate values, it could be anything.

---

You could fix your program like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
  int array[5];
  int* target = &array[1];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    const char* nstr[] = {"st", "nd", "rd", "th"};
    int index;
    if(i > 3)
      index = 3;
    else
      index = i;

    printf("Enter your %d%s item: ", i+1, nstr[index]);
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
  }
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    printf("Array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
  }

  printf("Target: %d\n", *target);
}
```

Output & input example:

```
Enter your 1st item: 1
Enter your 2nd item: 2
Enter your 3rd item: 3
Enter your 4th item: 4
Enter your 5th item: 5
Array[0] = 1
Array[1] = 2
Array[2] = 3
Array[3] = 4
Array[4] = 5
Target: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you haven't read this array like you. This is better :

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){ //taking 5 user inputs
    printf("Enter your %dst item: ", y+1);
    scanf("%d", &array[y]);
}
```

Note, that I read &array[y], but not &array[5]. You have to put to scanf as arg the adress of destination of data. It's tha same like

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){ //taking 5 user inputs
     printf("Enter your %dst item: ", y+1);
     scanf("%d", array+y);
}
```

So, your correct prog will be like this :

```
    int main(void) {

      int array[5]; //the array with x items
      //int target = array[1]; //target is any second value of the array I dont know what you want here

      for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++){ //taking 5 user inputs
          printf("Enter your %dst item: ", y+1);
          scanf("%d", array+y);
      }

      for (int x=0 ; x < 5; x++){ //printing out array
          printf("Array[%d] = %d\n", x, array[x]);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it did help me! The reason why I had so many input blocks was because I needed the program to say "1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th", because if I wrote just "th" then it would say "Enter your 1th item: " and so on. However if you've got an alternative way of achieving the same goal please let me know. Thanks!